# Tablesorter plugin with asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, jquery-plugins

I'm having strange results when using this two fellows because it only sort the page is viewing and I need to sort across pagination as well. Second, when the pagination numbers appear the asc and desc effects put the numbers on top or at the bottom. And last but not least, the grid is inside an updatepanel and when I try to click for a second time the header for sorting nothing happens, only if I press the shift button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it only sort the page is viewing and I need to sort across pagination as well

Is the pagination happening client-side or server-side?  It sounds like it's server-side.  If that's the case, then the jQuery plugin *can't* sort anything more than what's on the page, because from the perspective of JavaScript (which is client-side) there *are* no other records than the ones on the page.

> the asc and desc effects put the numbers on top or at the bottom

Are the numbers in table cells like the rest of the table?  Are they differentiated from the other rows in any way?  It sounds like the jQuery plugin is just sorting the table, regardless of the table's contents.  The server-side code which is rendering the table has no knowledge of the jQuery plugin and has no intention of catering to it.

For the more dynamic client-side table manipulation that you're looking for, I highly recommend using something like [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/).  It internally handles things like paging and sorting, so you wouldn't have to worry about reconciling your client-side and server-side code manually between otherwise mutually exclusive plugins/controls/frameworks.

It's a fairly significant shift from using server-side grid controls, so don't think of it as a drop-in replacement.  But being able to effectively use it will give you a lot of options for AJAX-friendly client-side interactions.  The main thing to keep in mind is to have a clear line of separation between the server-side code and the client-side code.  Have a separate server-side handler for responding to AJAX requests and treat it like a "web service" used by the client-side JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Now the problem is that I'm newbie in javascript, jquery and don't know too much about ajax. So how would I put the jqgrid to work with my gridview? The grid already does insert, modify and delete options. Does jqgrid will make me change too much code?

Comment: @maufonfa: It would make you change a _lot_ of code, yes.  The main problem is that you're blurring the lines between client-side code and server-side code.  If you just want to plug together some controls and have it all work, you may need some more advanced controls.  (Like something from Telerik, for example.)  For someone who's pretty new with plain ASP.NET webforms, JavaScript may be a steep learning curve.  It'll be worth it, but it's not a drop-in replacement.

Comment: But the Telerik controls must be paid right? Is there something open-source for this? Like the ajaxcontroltoolkit but with an enhanced gridview?

Comment: @maufonfa: There may very well be, and Google will be your friend there.  Honestly, I'm seeing a bigger issue here than just "what control should I use."  It's a matter of fully understanding how client-side code works and where it disconnects from server-side code.  Not wanting to pay money and not wanting to learn it are very often mutually exclusive requirements.  (And note that "learning it" is vastly outside the scope of what can be answered in a single Stack Overflow question.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do understand the difference between server and client side controls. I just thought there maybe a way to transfer server info to tablesorter. And for the learning I have a lot of interest but not just the time right now, just wanted to know if you had some quicker solution.